# Почему нельзя использовать goto в constexpr функциях?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, goto

Почему нельзя использовать `goto` в `constexpr` функциях?

```
constexpr auto foo() {
    hell: goto hell; // error: 'goto' in 'constexpr' function
}
```

Comment: ну как минимум, constexpr  не должна иметь побочных эффектов и быть такой, которую можно вычислить, Ваша функция к такой не относится и очень похожа на зловред для компилятора.

Comment: @KoVadim это для примера функция; любое использование `goto` в `constexpr` функции приводит к такой ошибке

Comment: да, я знаю. Но мой ответ не поменялся. goto слишком особая штука.

Comment: Потому что в стандарте написано, что там не должно быть `goto`.

Comment: "Потому что в стандарте написано" _ это не ответ.

Comment: Это хороший ответ. Это как спросить, почему if исполняет else ветку, когда условие не выполняется.

Comment: Потому что goto есть оператор времени выполнения.  . Это "иди туда(потом скажу куда)",  "сделай то то( скажу что)" _ гарантируй конкретный результат. Ни один компилятор "не позволит  издеваться над собой, потому что они стандартные.."

Comment: А статья https://habr.com/ru/post/228181/ по мне по теме

Comment: Какой-то нескладный получается интерпретатор, когда пытаешься сделать его для языка с goto (хотя, в бэйсике это никого не останавливало, а вот в современных скриптовых языках (их то обычно и интерпретируют) языка с goto не могу вспомнить)

Comment: Потому что в стандарте так сказано.

Answer (score 1):

От слишком строгих правил для `constexpr` функций постепенно избавляются. В С++23 с принятием [P2242](https://wg21.link/p2242) можно будет использовать метки и `goto` в `constexpr` функциях, но не в контексте *constant expression*.

[Пример](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Ccassert%3E%0A%0Aconstexpr+auto+foo()+%7B%0A++++if+consteval+%7B%0A++++++++//+can!%27t+use+!%27goto!%27%0A++++++++return+42%3B%0A++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++goto+test%3B%0A++++++++test:+return+43%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++static_assert(foo()+%3D%3D+42)%3B%0A++++assert(foo()+%3D%3D+43)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2b%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
#include <cassert>

constexpr auto foo() {
    if consteval {
        // can't use 'goto'
        return 42;
    } else {
        goto test;
        test: return 43;
    }
}

int main() {
    static_assert(foo() == 42);
    assert(foo() == 43);
}
```